# Use Highchart context menu provided in version v4.0.0

Tags: highcharts, contextmenu

Add Context menu on right cick of bar chart  ,Highchart API version  v4.0.0 . In newly version of highchart context menu is provided but i dont know how to use it .I need to add Context menu on right click .OLD version of API does not support Context Menu

Answer (score 0):

You can catch right click event by customEvents.js and then dispaly i.e hidden div which will be context menu.

http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/15/Custom-Events/